# Redirect express js route after a successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm working on express js app and the first page is a login / register page. in `login.js` I have used `passport` and `JWT` to authenticate the user and redirect the successfully logged in user to the main page of the application:

```
function login(req, res, next){
    User.forge({ email: req.body.email }).fetch().then(result => {
        if (!result) {
            return res.status(401).send('user not found');
        }
        result.authenticate(req.body.password).then(user => {
            const payload = { id: user.id };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY);
            console.log(res.statusCode); // just for testing
            res.redirect('/mypage');         
        }).catch(err => {
            return res.status(401).send({ err: err });
        });
    });
}
```

for `mypage` route in the express I have

```
app.get('/mypage', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/view/mypage.html'));
    }

});
```

it works but the problem is even not logged in users can access that route via `localhost:PORT/mypage`.

first, is redirecting to another route is the way to go? what is the best and approporiate way to redirect to another rendered page after successful login?

Comment: If people can bypass the authentication - you would need to check if token was found in headers of the actual request- if not - redirect them to login.. Something like `const token = req.headers['authorization'];` and then a quick comparrison if they match would be working for you

Comment: Any luck with the example I've given you?

Comment: yes, thanks hips

Comment: You are welcome - in that case you might consider to also accept the answer in case future visitors have a similar issue  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a middleware guard that checks if the request actually contains a token in its header.

Here's a generic example:

```
/* ================================================
  INFO: @MIDDLEWARE - Used to grab user's token from headers
  ================================================ */

  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    // INFO: Getting the generated token from headers
    const token = req.headers['authorization']; // Create token found in headers
    // INFO: Check if token was found in headers
    if (!token) {
       let content = 
            `<body style="margin: 0px;">
            <div style="width: -webkit-fill-available; height: -webkit-fill-available;">
              <div class="col-sm-12 " style="padding-top: 1em; padding-left: 1em;">
                <h3 style="color:#666666;">Direct navigation via the browser's URL-bar forbidden!</h3>
                <p style="color:#666666;">Please use the navigation provided by the application only.</p>
                <a style="color:#800101; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;" href="http://${stdoutIP}" target="_self">Back to Login</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            </body>`;
        res.send(content);
    }
    else {
      // INFO: Verify the token is valid
      jwt.verify(token, "myVerySecretSecret", (err, decoded) => {
          // INFO: Check if error is expired or invalid
          //console.log("token verification:",token);

          if (err) {
            // INFO: Return error for token validation
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Token invalid: ' + err });
          } else {
            // INFO: Create global variable to use in any request beyond
            req.decoded = decoded;
            // INFO: Exit middleware
            next();
          }
        });
      }
  });
```